# Models for n-p junction

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, material-science

Sorry if my question is too basic, but I have little knowledge in solid state physics. I would like to know what are the best theoretical models to describe what's going on doped semiconductors.

More specifically, I want to know if there is something that explains the apparent force that pushes the electrons from the n-type to the p-type even in the absence of external potential, that is, before the equilibrium in the zero bias (imagine we put together a n-type and a p-type that are uniformly doped at first).

By the way, "diffusion current" is a term that may be applied to the movement of the charge carriers across n-type and p-type or just to the case of non-uniform concentration in a region with only one type?

It seems to me that the nature of this "force" is not electrical, once the two regions of a n-p junction are electrically neutral. Even if we consider non-uniform concentration of charge carriers, if the material is more n-doped in a certain region, this region has more electrons but also more protons. So, if I am right, what is the nature of this attraction and how can one make sense of this?